# iOS: NSInternalInconsistencyException When Seguing to New View Controller

Tags: ios, segue

If a core data check is empty, I want to leave a certain view controller and segue to a different view controller.

The core data check is called from View WIllAppear. 
Right now, I have the command to make the transition at the end of the core data pull. If the pull comes back empty ,then I trigger the code to segue to another view controller.

This is causing a problem since the page is not yet loaded when I ask IOS to go to a different page.  However, I really don't want to the page to load first.

Also,  I don't want to move this code out of viewWillAppear, for example, to viewDidLoad as I want to do a fresh check of the data every time someone visits the screen.

Can anyone suggest right way to do this?

Here is my code:

In viewWillAppear:

```
[self updateInterface];
```

In updateInterface:

```
self.item = [self getLatestItem:userid inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
```

in getLatestItem

```
 NSArray *matches = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (!matches ||[matches count]<1) {
            // handle error
             self.noNewItems=1;
 [self gotoListChallenges];
        }  else {
            NSLog(@"got at least one match");
            item = [matches lastObject];
        }
        return item;
}
- (void) gotoListItems {
     UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
    listItemsVC *listVC =
    [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listItems"];
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: listVC];
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You either need to do it in `viewDidAppear` so that you have an active view controller to present the new view controller, or perhaps refactor your app so that you check before you present this view controller and present the correct view controller directly.  Since you are using a UINavigationController you can have the earlier view controller pre-populate the nav stack so that the user can move "back" from the `listItems` view controller to the one you are showing here.

Comment: Makes sense.  Complicating things here is that the VC I want to avoid if data is empty is also the entry point to the app.  So if I don't go there first, it does not set up the tab bar controller....